# About symmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I am confused about symmetric bilinear forms.
Here is my question:
Let b is a positive definite symmetric bilinear form on real vector space. 
Is b non-degenerate?

Comment: I think $0$ is usually considered positive-definite in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To say that $b$ is non-degenerate is the same as to say that there is no $x$ such that the function $f_x: V \to V$ given by
$$
y \mapsto b(x, y)
$$
is identically the zero function.

To say that $b$ is positive definite means that for any $x$, $b(x, x) > 0$. In particular, $f_x(x) = b(x, x) \neq 0$ and so $f_x$ is not identically the zero function.

Comment: Isn't there any way to prove that? I am trying to show that is b symmetric bilinear respectively positive,negative and indefinite, b is non-degenerate and controversely while b is non-degenerate is b pos, neg or indefinite?